# Find the inverse of this function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

When a camera flash goes off, the batteries immediately begin to recharge
the flash’s capacitor, which stores electric charge given by

$Q(t) = Q_0(1-e^{-t/a})$

(The maximum charge capacity is $Q_0$ and $t$ is measured in seconds.)

(a) Find the inverse of this function and explain its meaning.

(b) How long does it take to recharge the capacitor to $90 \%$ of capacity if
$a=2$

Comment: Seriously.  Do you know what an inverse function is?

Answer (score 1):

dividing by $$Q_0$$ we obtain
$$\frac{Q(t)}{Q_0}=1-e^{-t/a}$$ solving this for $$-\frac{t}{a}$$ and taking the logarithm we have
$$-\frac{t}{a}=\ln\left(1-\frac{Q(t)}{Q_0}\right)$$ after multiplying by $a$ and $-1$ we get
$$t=-a\ln\left(1-\frac{Q(t)}{Q_0}\right)$$